How to set max row height in pandas
One column in my pandas dataframe is too long. How can I set max row height (not number of rows in a dataframe) in pandas so that I can truncate the cells with too much content and have a balanced view of all columns?
Not asking for
pd.set_option('display.height', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)

which sets the max number of rows in a dataframe.

What datatype do you have in that column? Strings?

Hey @EvertAcosta yes I had long text descriptions/strings

Don't shorten the data by options as you would lose data. Also, you may need a different configuration for length of the short version later.
Instead, do it this way:
First create a new column (e.g. named short) from the column that has long data in it (e.g. named long) .
Then use the .apply() method to create another column based on the first column and manually get the first N characters to create the second column. Then using pandas only select the other column and the new one (not including the column with long rows).
You can work with the data but not losing the long data. When ever you need the original text with no truncating, the data is presented in the original column.
I prefer using the approach below instead of using .apply() method as it is very short and handy. Remember that this is a small trick while the .apply() method can be used to manually get every row and get the first N characters.
df["short"] = df["long"].str[:10]

